# JavaScript infinite loop when updating firebase Realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to allow non-signed in users the ability to add items to a basket.
When the button is clicked the code below is run.
By default the basket value doesn't exist, so the if statement should create a value.
The else statement will add 1 to existing value.

This seems to cause an infinite loop and the number in the database jumps to 1016.
I've probably approached this in the wrong way and can't see how to stop this.

```
function addToBasket(sessionID){
  firebase.database().ref('tempUser/' + sessionID).on('value', function (snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    
    if (data == null) {
      //update
      firebase.database().ref('tempUser/' + sessionID).set({
        basket: 1,
      });
    }
    
    else {
      //get basket number
      var currentBasket = Object.values(data);
      //turn string into a integer 
      let number = parseFloat(currentBasket) ;
      //add one to the value
      var newNumber = number + 1;
      //upload new number to db
      firebase.database().ref('tempUser/' + sessionID).set({
        basket: newNumber,
      });
    }

  });
}
```

[image: Firebase Real Time Database]

Thank you in advance for any help or advice,
Connor

Comment: Do you expect `data` to be an object or a number? Object.values is used to return an array consisting of the values within an object. `parseFloat` returns `NAN` when used against an array.

if `data` is a number, just reference it directly. ```let newNumber = data  + 1;```

if data is an object of cart items, you need to determine it's length. Try ```let number = currentBasket.length();```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, pointed me in the right direction. Saw the NAN return you mentioned, I was expecting it to be a number but it was an array. I have now got it working with numbers but the code still seems to keeps looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attaching a permanent listener to `tempUser/$sessionID` in your database. This means that Firebase immediately calls your callback method with the current value in the database, and then calls the same callback each time the value changes.

Since *inside* this call, you are changing the data with `tempUser/$sessionID`, that triggers the same callback again. Which then makes another change to `tempUser/$sessionID`, which triggers the callback again. And again, and again...

If you only want to change the value once, use `once()` instead of `on()`:

```
 firebase.database().ref('tempUser/' + sessionID).once('value', ...
```